# Extracting Marginal Distribution by Monte Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, marginal-distribution

Suppose we know the distribution of a variable $x$ is $g(X)$, and we also know the conditional distribution of a variable $y$ given $x$ is $f(y|x)$. It has been shown that (such as in [this book, p. 52](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946888) ) by

1. Draw $x^*$~$g(x)$
2. Draw $y^*$~$f(y|x)$

After $n$ draws, the quantities $y_1,...,y_n$ are an iid sample from the marginal density $J(y)$. I understand that the pairs $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$ are an iid sample from the joint distribution $Q(x,y)$, but I still try to figure out the intuition/theory about why $y_1,...,y_n$ are an iid sample from the marginal density $J(y)$. Can anyone help? Thanks.

p.s. I know the answer to [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213052/sampling-from-marginal-distribution-using-conditional-distribution?rq=1) explains it but I still don't get why ignoring $x$'s equals to integrating out them.

Comment: This question has been discussed many times on X validated: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/213057/7224) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/340610/7224) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/327465/7224).